# Avoiding Python NameError when rewriting script with user defined functions for ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, nameerror

I am rewriting a script for Python 3.6 and ArcGIS Pro compatibility and it seems like user defined functions will be necessary to clean it up. I am fairly new. I separated the code block into two functions and I would like to call the first function in the beginning of the second function. I'd also like to call the first function near the bottom but I'm getting a NameError. Here is the code block that I am working on.

```
def select_address():
    for lyr in m.listLayers():  
        if lyr.name == "LOCATION.addresspoint":
            CoaAddresses = lyr
            selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(CoaAddresses,"NEW_SELECTION", expression)
            return(selection)

def found_address():
    select_address()
    print(selection)
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(selection): #retrieve address of selected feature
        selectedAddress = row.FULL_STREET_NAME  #this variable used later for legend
        return(selectedAddress)

select_address()

results = arcpy.GetCount_management(selection) #return number of features selected
```

the error I get:

> results = arcpy.GetCount_management(selection) #return number of
>   features selected
>
> NameError: name 'selection' is not defined

Shouldn't `selection` be defined in the `def select_address():` portion of the script?

Comment: Just because Python permits spaghetti code with respect to variable scoping doesn't mean it's good practice. Your code will be far more maintainable if functions which set variables either return the value or modify a list, dictionary, or object which is provided as input. And script modernization is a prime time to eliminate deprecated *old-style* cursor use in favor of faster, more Pythonic DA cursors.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand your advice. I'm not setting any global variables within my functions here, so this block of code is okay? You're referring to setting a global variable inside of a function?

Comment: You have several maintainability flaws in this script. 1) The layer name is hard-coded in a function 2) `select_address` returns from inside a loop, so you'll never find an error with duplicate layer names 3) `select_address` returns a value which is ignored (twice) 4)  `found_address` is defined, but never called 5) `found_address` ignores the result of `select_address` 6) You're not using a DA cursor 7) `found_address` returns from within a cursor, which is never deleted, and for which multiple rows are never tested. Global variables should only be used when it's the only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selection` is a local variable within `select_address()`, so you can't use it outside the scope of that function.

`selection = select_address()` should fix the name error

Comment: Yes, that fixed the NameError. The "expression"  variable used in the SelectLayerByAttribute_management function is assigned outside and before the select_address function is defined, is that okay or do I need to assign it inside of the function?

Comment: If its a global variable (i.e. defined outside any other function) you should be able to use it anywhere, including within a function. Some people would probably say this is bad practice and that you should modify the function to only use local variables, taking in any outside information as an argument/parameter. But this probably isn't necessary in your case